# Outlook 2013 hangs for a minute or two if the user tries to open the email with sharepoint task in a disconnected network

Tags: 2010, outlook, windows-authentication, exchange, network

Have you come across the following scenario anytime with SharePoint outlook task?

•   SharePoint task assigned to a user and embedded in the outlook email.
•   Works perfectly when connected to ActioNet network
•   Outlook hangs for a minute or two if the user tries to open the email in a disconnected network.

I understand that if we select “Cached Exchange Mode” in Outlook, cached versions of SharePoint resources are used in an offline/disconnected environment and later synchronized when the user connects to the ActioNet network. But it doesn’t help find why it takes a minute or two open the email. Have anyone ever come across this issue?